# Checking if two Python values are equal isn't working even when they're equal

Tags: python

The last section of the code does not do what I want it to do. It should be true if `checkdigit` is the same as `validdigit`, so it should print 'The GTIN-8 Code is valid' if not it should say 'The GTIN-8 is not valid'

```
gtin = input('Enter a GTIN-8 Code: ')
if len(gtin) == 8 and gtin.isdigit() == True:
    print ('Comparing')
else:
    print ('Error, 8 digits have not been inputted and/or letters were      inputted')

gtinlist = list(gtin)

print (gtinlist) # not needed

checkdigit = gtinlist[7]

print ('This is the check digit given: '+str(checkdigit))

no1 = int(gtinlist[0])*3
no2 = int(gtinlist[1])*1
no3 = int(gtinlist[2])*3
no4 = int(gtinlist[3])*1
no5 = int(gtinlist[4])*3
no6 = int(gtinlist[5])*1
no7 = int(gtinlist[6])*3

print (no1,no2,no3,no4,no5,no6,no7) # not needed

added = (no1+no2+no3+no4+no5+no6+no7)

print (added) #not needed

m = (added + 9) // 10 * 10

validdigit = m - added

print (validdigit)
print (checkdigit)

if (validdigit)==(checkdigit)==True:
    print('This GTIN-8 Code is valid')
else:
    print('This GTIN-8 Code is not valid')
```

Comment: can you give expected input and output

Comment: Can you provide some testcases (code working/not working)?

Comment: Just a reminder that `'123' != 123`. `isdigit()` is not the same as `int(str)`

Comment: Your problem lies here: 
`m = (added + 9) // 10 * 10` since
`validdigit = m - added`
m is the same as added..... so it's going to be zero...... are you sure this is what you wanted?

Also
`if (validdigit)==(checkdigit)==True:` you don't need the end ==True.....

Comment: In order to better understand what is going on, try printing repr: `print(repr(validdigit))`, `print(repr(checkdigit))`. That will usually make it easier to spot the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Verify the data types in your equality check.

If you change the print lines near the end to:

```
print validdigit, type(validdigit)
print checkdigit, type(checkdigit)
```

You will see that one is a string and one is an integer.

Comparing these data types will always result in False. There is no implicit type conversion for int vs. str. In other words, `'8' != 8` in Python.  Convert one to int or the other to str and you'll be fine.